# How to use Find to highlight words and retain highlighting?

Tags: find-and-replace, microsoft-word-2013

I'm using Word 2013. I can use the Find feature to pick out words from a document, then Highlight All examples that meet the search criteria. But the highlighting disappears when I try to edit the document or close the Find window. Is there any way to actually permanently highlight all items that match search criteria, without having to jump to each item and press the highlight button, or manually select each item?

Answer (score 14):

Choose the colour you wish to highlight your words in

In the FIND, enter your word

In REPLACE, type ^&

In FORMAT (for replace), select Highlight.

Comment: Worked for me, @LeoKing might wanna consider accepting this.

Comment: Not working for me, maybe I'm missing a detail...